# Making perl run on a file

Tags: regex, perl, input

**Intro.** I have the following line of code:

```
perl -pe 's;(\//(.*?)\\glft );;g'
```

Its purpose is to take tex source code for linguistically annotated texts in a Native American language and to extract just the English translation.  The translations are scattered throughout the document, but are always immediately preceded by `\glft` and terminated by `//`.  The code therefore deletes everything from (and including) `\\` up to (and including) `\glft`.

**Problem.** I'm running perl on the Terminal on my macbook pro.  This imposes a stingy limit on how many characters I can run the code on at one time.  Can I instruct perl to run the code on a whole file?  I don't mind if it extracts the output and plonks it a new file, or puts it at the end of the input file, or any other sensible option.

**Comment.** I'm sure this is a low-level question, but I started using perl only yesterday.  Some sample code is included below.

---

> He was told by Se\~nor Ignacio: ``All right, give me two hundred now and she will be yours.''// \endgl \xe   \ex % \indx{hujuei@{\emph{huju\'ei}, \emph{huj\'uei} `then'}}% \indx{wie@{\emph{wie}, \emph{wi\'e}, \emph{w\'ie}`give'; \emph{w\'iet\ss{}e} `give{\sc.pass}'}}% \indx{wi@{\emph{wi}, \emph{wisi}, \emph{w\'isi}`two'}}% \indx{tiwitati@{\emph{t\k{\'i}wit\'ati} `hundred'}}% \indx{witad@{\emph{witad}, \emph{w\'itad}`alone'}}% \indx{kzza'a@{\emph{kha'a}, \emph{kha'\'a}, \emph{kh\'a'a} `father, se\~nor'}}% \indx{kur@{\emph{k\'ur}`captive'}}% \indx{u@{\emph{u}, \emph{'u}, \emph{'\'u}, \emph{'\k u} {\sc dim}}}% \indx{tiutsze@{\emph{t\'i\k ut\ss{}e}, \emph{t\k i\k ut\ss{}\'e} `leave{\sc.pass}'}}% % \begingl Huj\'uei [then]      % \zero- [\sc 3s-] + w\'ie- [give-] + t\ss{}e- [\sc pass-] + van [\sc pnct]      % wi- [two-] + t\k iwit\'ati, [hundred]      % w\'itad [alone]      % Kha'a [Se\~nor]      % Patr\'isu [Patricio]      % 'a- [\sc :3s:3s-] + kur- [captive-] + 'u- [\sc dim-] + t\'i\k u- [leave-] + t\ss{}e- [\sc pass-] + va-- [\sc pnct--] + k. [\sc sub]  \endilg \glft Then two hundred was given and the little slave was left to Se\~nor Patricio alone.// \endgl \xe   {\medskip\footnotesize   \noindent We have changed the translation from`he was given the two hundred' to `the two hundred was given', in light of the zero agreement on \emph{w\'iet\ss{}evan}`was given'.  In \getref{n23}, \emph{benwi\'eik'a} `give it to me now' agrees, via the prefix \emph{ben}, with the second singular agent, first singular recipient, and third singular object`money': it is not agentless \emph{'in} {\sc :1s:3s}, benefactiveless \emph{'a} {\sc 2s:3s}, or themeless \emph{bei} {\sc 2s:1s}. By contrast, \emph{w\'iet\ss{}evan} agrees with just one third singular argument: if it agreed with both the recipient and object, the prefix would be \emph{'a} {\sc :3s:3s}, as in the next clause of the same sentence.     We hypothesise that the agreeing argument is `the two hundred', as the obvious alternatives seem less plausible given what we find elsewhere (that {\sc :3s:3s} \emph{'a} has been elided or that \emph{w\'ie} may optionally fail to agree with its patient and instead treat the recipient as a direct object).  The explicit remention of Se\~nor Patricio in the next clause, and the concomitant indirect-cum-direct-object agreement \emph{'a}, might be taken in favour of viewing him as absent for the clause containing`was given'. % \medskip\ % \TH{}'s translates \emph{t\'i\k ut\ss{}e} as `be owned', but this makes it surprising that  \emph{Kha'a Patr\'isu} agrees with the verb as a dative (a passivised agent would bear \emph{ba}`by' and would not agree) and that \emph{kur-'u} `little captive' is incorporated (a passivised object would bear \emph{de} {\sc bas} and be free).  Consequently, we prefer the gloss`be left' for which a dative syntax is more natural (`\emph x was left to \emph y'); this also fits better with \getref{d6}.  (We have not seen an active counterpart to this root, but TH records the overtly causitive/passive pair \emph{t\k{\'i}w-\k i}`keep', \emph{t\k{\'i}w-\k e} `be kept' is attested.)     \medskip}   \ex<n25> % \indx{pzi@{\emph{p'i}`head'}}% \indx{pza@{\emph{p'a} `water'}}% \indx{hwe@{\emph{hwe}, \emph{hw\'e}`take'; \emph{hw\'et\ss{}e} `take{\sc.pass}'}}% \indx{misatu@{\emph{m\'isat\'u}`church'}}% \indx{kzzai@{\emph{kh\k a\k i} `name ({\sc v})' (see also \emph{kh\k a})}}% % \begingl \zero- [\sc 3s:3s-] + P'i- [head\ct{12}-] + p'a- [water\ct{12}-] + hw\'e- [take-] + van [\sc pnct]      % m\'isat\'u-- [church--] + 'at, [\sc loc]      % P\'etra-- [Petra--] + m [\sc quot]      % \zero- [\sc 3s:3s-] + kh\k a\k i- [name-] + van. [\sc pnct]  \endilg \glft He took her to the church to be baptised and christened her Petra.//

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your expression is correct, run this command:

```
perl -p -i.orig -e 's;(\//(.*?)\\glft );;g' input.txt
```

It will save the original input as `input.txt.orig`, and `input.txt` will contain the fixed file.

Another way is to use your command with shell redirection:

```
perl -pe 's;(\//(.*?)\\glft );;g' < input.txt > output.txt
```

It will take input from `input.txt` and put the processed result into `output.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, but betraying my level of ignorance here, `input.txt` here means a file named `input` with the extension `.txt`, right?  In other words, I have to save my (all ascii) `.tex` file as `.txt` first.

Comment: How does perl know the location of the file?

Comment: In my example it takes input from `input.txt` in the current working directory (the one that you are in, maybe it's your home directory if you did not change it—type `pwd` in the command line to know it. You can point it to your `.tex` file as well, no need to rename: `perl -pe '...' < file.tex > result.tex`

Comment: That's great.  Looking forward to trying it out!

Comment: Maybe look into a Perl module to parse tex file like [LaTeX::TOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/LaTeX::TOM)

Comment: Yep, that's working fine.  The crucial last step was, as you said, to enter `pwd` into the command line and then to put the target file there.

Comment: +Daniel Harbour Just an (off-topic) advice, spend some time on reading some doc about using the command line in Mac OS X (e.g. http://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/command-line/ — the first link from Google, or any other). Doing file-related operations in the terminal is often *way* faster than in Finder or any UI tool, especially when you need to perform the same operation with many files.